# Как сделать изображения spotify.png и soundcloud.png под надписью с классом main-hero-text?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
.header-links-list__item {
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.header-links-list__item a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.header-links-list__container {
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-hero-text {
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 350px;
  padding-left: 220px;
}

.podcast-services__item {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.podcast-services__item img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>floydpower | первая верстка</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/imports.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index/header.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index/footer.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-links-list__container">
      <ul class='header-links-list' style="display: flex; list-style: none;">
        <li class='header-links-list__item'><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class='header-links-list__item'><a href="#">Episodes</a></li>
        <li class='header-links-list__item'><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class='header-links-list__item'><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main-info__container">
      <div class="info-about-hero" style="display: flex;">
        <img src="images/man.png" alt="man" style="height: 873px; width: 650px; padding-top: 119px; padding-left: 60px;">
        <h1 class="main-hero-text">Take your podcast to the<br>next <span class="main-hero__word">level</span></h1>
        <div class="podcast-services__container">
          <ul style="display: flex; list-style: none;">
            <li class="podcast-services__item">
              <a href="#"><img src="images/spotify.png" alt="spotify"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="podcast-services__item">
              <a href="#"><img src="images/soundcloud.png" alt="soundcloud"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

нужно чтобы изображения  spotify.png и soundcloud.png находились под надписью с классом main-hero-text. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

z-index у текста сделать больше:

```
.main-hero-text {
  position: relative;     /*или absolute*/
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: к сожалению, не работает